# How can I create registration page without refreshing in Asp.Net MVC with Razor?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, razor, asp.net-identity

I need to get advice about in Registration Page in Asp.net MVC5 and razor page.
what is the best way for it:
My scenario is I have a registration process in three-step :
In the First Step, the client enters a username and captcha.
In the Second Phase client Enter the Phone number and send SMS by Identity.
If the Entered validation code was code the confirmation message and welcome page appears.

An easy way is we can make a three action result by the separate razor view.
But the problem is I need to do the noted process without any page refreshing.
what is the best way to do it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can use AJAX by posting your values and receiving informations or views from your server.

Comment: ok, thanks but what I mean is what architecture needs for this process for example one view for some action or other method...

Comment: you can use different methods in your index-file and each method returns data and new view till the user input is like expected. One Index-View and multiple subviews.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I won't use it in Asp.net MVC 5, not in Asp.net core and I couldn't use ViewComponent in MVC5.

Comment: you tagged your question with razor and i thought, you need this for asp net core. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve your task with following steps

1. Download jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js from [here](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/blob/master/src/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js) and add a link in your layout.cshtml
2. create a Components folder in your pages folder
3. create a Register folder in your Components folder

[image: Folder structure]

4. add a file for your dto

**RegisterDto.cs**

```
    public class RegisterDto
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Validation { get; set; }
}
```

5. create your first form.
   I created a new form in the index.cshtml. Here you can see, that I'm using ajax for handling the form. Use a container for replacing with your viewcomponents. In my example, my DOM Object is "content".

**index.cshtml**

```
<div id="content">
<div class="col-6">
    <form method="post" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" asp-page="/Index" asp-page-handler="SubPage1" data-ajax-update="#content">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="RegisterDto.Email"></label>
            <input asp-for="RegisterDto.Email" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="RegisterDto.FirstName"></label>
            <input asp-for="RegisterDto.FirstName" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="RegisterDto.SurName"></label>
            <input asp-for="RegisterDto.SurName" class="form-control" />
        </div> 

        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">next</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

6. Create a new ViewComponentClass. Over the page-parameter you can switch between pages, and the registerDto is your model you can pass between pages.

**RegisterViewComponent.cs**

```
public class RegisterViewComponent : ViewComponent
{


    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string Page, RegisterDto registerDto)
    {

        return View(Page, registerDto);
    }
}
```

7. create your views in your viewcomponent.

**SubPage1.cshtml**

```
<div class="col-6">
<form method="post" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" asp-page-handler="SubPage2" data-ajax-update="#content">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Email"></label>
        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control disabled" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>
        <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control disabled" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="SurName"></label>
        <input asp-for="SurName" class="form-control disabled" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Phone"></label>
        <input asp-for="Phone" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">next</button>
</form>
```

**SubPage2.cshtml**

```
    <div class="col-6">
    <form method="post" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" asp-page-handler="SubPage3" data-ajax-update="#content">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Email"></label>
            <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control disabled" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>
            <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control disabled" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="SurName"></label>
            <input asp-for="SurName" class="form-control disabled" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Phone"></label>
            <input asp-for="Phone" class="form-control disabled" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Validation"></label>
            <input asp-for="Validation" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Done</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**default.cshtml**

```
<h1>done</h1>
```

done!